# How do I access an exported function in another exported function in same file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fetch the user data in the login function from the loadUser function. But it is refusing to run, I am not sure what is wrong here?

I think you can call an exported function in the same file?

```
// Login User
export const login = (formData) => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    heraders: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
  try {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/auth', formData, config);
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data
    });
    console.log('Calling load user here?');
    loadUser();
    console.log('loadUser did not run?');
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_FAIL,
      payload: err.response.data.msg
    });
  }
}

// Load User
export const loadUser = () => async dispatch => {
  console.log('Is this running');
  if (localStorage.token) {
    setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
  }
  console.log('GETTING USER');
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('/api/auth');
    dispatch({ 
      type: USER_LOADED,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({ 
      type: AUTH_ERROR
    });
  }
}
```

I expect the loadUser function to run, but it don't.

Comment: `loadUser()` returns a function that does the actual work, but your code does not call that function.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call the `loadUser` function from within the login function by its name like you would any other JavaScript function.

Here is how you can update the login function to call the `loadUser` function:

```
// Login User
export const login = (formData) => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
  try {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/auth', formData, config);
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data
    });
    console.log('Calling load user here?');

    // Call the loadUser function, passing in dispatch as an argument
    loadUser()(dispatch);

    console.log('loadUser did not run?');
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_FAIL,
      payload: err.response.data.msg
    });
  }
}
```

Since the `loadUser` function is an `async` function that takes dispatch as an argument, you will need to call it like this: `loadUser()(dispatch)`.